# How to support jpeg in PHP?

Tags: linux, php, apache-2.4

I can see gif/png support in the output of `phpinfo()`.

I built PHP with `--with-gd`. But only GIF Support and PNG Support are in the output of `phpinfo()`. How do I enable JPEG Support?

Do I need to have infos bout JPEG in the output of phpinfo too?

Comment: Why are you compiling software yourself?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think he wants to compensate something which his distro misses (f.e. gd module in php).

Answer (score 2):

To enable support for `jpeg` add `--with-jpeg-dir=DIR`. See more http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

You must have installed `libjpeg`